# how to give path to custom page tpl for content type

Tags: php, url, drupal, drupal-7

I want to give the path for custom page tpl which I have created for specific content type. 'test_insights' is my content type name.I have created custom page tpl in the folder

```
project_name/themes/themename/templates/page--test_insights.tpl.php
```

I want to know how to give the path for created tpl 
now I tried `http://localhost/project_name/test_insights`

I caught the error as The requested page "/project_name/test_insights" could not be found.

Comment: your custom .tpl is already working? Paths are controlled via HOOK_menu(). Or if you have the Path Auto module installed, when editing a node you should have a "ÜRL path settings" tab where you can set a URL alias

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a custom path, I'd recommend using the **Pathauto module**. It will generate custom paths based on tokens.

It sounds like you're trying to navigate to the template file, but the template file isn't actual content. You must first create a piece of content (a node) of the content type test_insights. When you're creating a node, you'll have the option to either `Generate automatic URL alias` (Using pathauto) or manually entering a custom path. Both options are located under `URL path settings`, when creating or editing a node.